# How to properly use Joda-Time Instant method

Tags: java, android, jodatime

In my app that counts difference between two hours I use Joda-Time `Instant` class, but something is wrong or I don't really know how to use it. My code looks like:

```
Instant start = Instant.now(); //to set current system time
textView.setText(start); //to display current time in textView
```

Sadly there's an error that says:

> cannot resolve method 'setText(org.joda.time.Instant)

How can I display current time properly?

Comment: What is `textView`, probably its type doesn't exist, have you actually imported `DateTime`?

Comment: Well, what do you mean what is `textView`? :) textView is the place where i want to hour be displayed

Comment: `textView` is a reference to some object of type `...`, i'm asking what the type is :).

Answer (score 2):

`textView.setText` accepts `String` parameters. You should pass `Instant` as a `String`:

```
Instant start = Instant.now();
textView.setText(start.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) set up with your preferred output format, you will probably want this:

```
textView.setText(DATE_TIME_FORMATTER.print(start));
```

Comment: (Or `start.toString(DATE_TIME_FORMATTER)`, if you prefer).